# How can I do the equivalent of a foreach in a while loop

Tags: java

If I have a `for-each` loop like:

```
for (int point : v[i]) {
```

where `v` is a `linked list <integer> array`. How can I do the same thing but using a while loop instead?

Comment: Is this homework? [Have a look](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm)!

Comment: It is easy to find out, as the translation is given in the JLS. But why would you want to? It's not "more efficient" or so.

Answer (score 0):

this is the idea

```
    int i = 0;
    int length = v.length;

    while(i < length){
       //do other stuff
       i++;

    }
```

Comment: look again at the order of `i++` and *stuff*

Comment: you are right about the order , changed that but again I my whole point was to put iterate over array using while loop.. if v is linked list or something, ofcourse the code will change